# Binding Kendo Grid with Complex Model in MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to show dynamic columns in my Kendo Grid keeping one column fixed.
I have a complex model in my application, here are the two models below.

```
public class Product
{
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    public int ProductQty { get; set; }

    public double ProductPrice { get; set; }
}

public class ProductLocation
{
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public List<Product> products { get; set; }
}
```

I am passing my model ProductLocation to View where my Kendo Grid is, I have populated my Model in my controller.

Below is my Kendo Grid, I have passed my Model to it, and I have used a foreach loop so that I can iterate for showing my dynamic column (Product), but I was unable to achieve my objective. I need the Product columns will generate dynamically keeping the Location column fixed. The Product column may change according to location, so I need dynamic generation of columns in my Kendo Grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyNamespace.ProductLocation>()
        .Name("ProductDataGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(x => x.Location ).Width(25).HtmlAttributes(new { title = " #= Location # " }); //Tooltip

            //foreach (var prod in Model)
            //{
            //    columns.Group(group => group
            //    .Title(eqp.EqpType)
            //    .Columns(info =>
            //    {
            //        //info.Bound(prod.ProductId).Title("AVL").Width(15);
            //        //info.Bound(prod.ProductQty).Title("DMG").Width(15);
            //        //info.Bound(prod.ProductPrice).Title("RSV").Width(15);

            //    })
            //    .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" })
            //);
            //}
        })
        .Selectable()
        .AutoBind(false)
        .Pageable()
        .Scrollable(builder => builder.Enabled(true).Height("100%"))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
        .PageSize(10)
        .Read(read => read.Action("MyActionMethod", "MyController"))

    )

.Navigatable()
    .Pageable(p => p
                  .PageSizes(true)
                  .Refresh(true)
                  .ButtonCount(10)
                  )
```

)

Please suggest any solution for it so that i can generate the Product column in dynamic way.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to revisit this design...what if the first ProductLocation has 2 Products and second one has 3 Products?  You are essentially trying to create a grid with 4 columns on the first row and 7 columns on the second, etc.  This is not how grids work, every row has to have the same number(and type) of columns.  I think you need to flatten the Grid model(Location|ProductID|ProductQty|ProductPrice) and have one row per product and then GroupBy Location.  Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you are trying to do?  Perhaps a mock-up picture would make it clear?

Comment: Every location will come with fixed number of columns for a group of location from the controller, but the number of columns can change if the location gets change in search filter. So, now the situation comes here for dynamic column creation according to the location change from the search criteria.